# How to get last action-type dispatched on the store from the store itself?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I'm creating a component that handles the state with **Redux** architecture (yes, this is probably bad by definition because a component should delegate the state to the app but anyway).

This component accepts different **props**. My problem comes when I have to handle a callback. Let's put a practical example to picture this better.

Let's say we need a component like `<App onSubmit={() => {}} />`.

We could **create a store** when the component gets **mount**, so then all inner components can dispatch actions/subscribe changes/etc.

The attempt could be to have an **action** called `submit()`. This way the **store** will know there's a change to apply so **any subscriber** will know and somebody will call this **onSubmit** callback.

So the code would look like:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor (props) {
     super(props)
     this.subscriber = this.subscriber.bind(this)
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    this.store = createStore()
    this.store.subscribe(this.subscriber)
  }
  subscriber (action) {
    if (action.type === 'submit')
      this.props.onSubmit()
  }
  render () {
    return (
      <Provider store={this.store}>
         <FooComponent />
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}
```

The problem is that, although `subscriber` is called on every action dispatched, **subscriber can't know what was the last action dispatched**. So there's no way to know when to call `onSubmit`.

- How can we use `subscriber` to know changes on the store?
- Should I stop trying a redux arquitecture in here?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is an anti-pattern in Redux.

There is no such thing as “the last action” because Redux reserves the right to notify you just once in case of several nested dispatches.

Instead, you should perform the local side effect *together* with the action. Redux Thunk is a popular way to do this. If you need more decoupling, you might enjoy Redux Saga instead.